# Android emulator is launched but not attached to the development environment?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

This problem happened after I moved the SDK and tools directories out of the system drive (to save space).

the problem is that, whenever I launch the emulator, either from Visual Studio, VSCode or Android Studio,
the emulator is launched but never attached to the project (can't launch the app).

I modified the *.ini files of the AVDs to point to the new AVD location (without this, the emulator couldn't be launched).

I have these variables (updated to the new location):

```
ANDROID_ROOT B:\Android\android-sdk
ANDROID_SDK_HOME B:\Users\m_sha\.android
```

When I run the emulator from the command line (on Windows), this is the reply:

```
B:\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator @Pixel_3_API_28
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

The `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` should be `B:\Users\m_sha` not `B:\Users\m_sha\.android`

and to run the emulator from the command line, I used the emulator tool in the emulator folder not tools folder, so this worked:

```
B:\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator @Pixel_3_API_28
```